# Вызов функции php из javaScript

Tags: javascript, php, html, веб-программирование

Мне нужно обрабатывать нажатие кнопок через ajax и по нажатию одной из них вызывать функцию php и передавать в нее параметры, потом из нее так же вызывать функцию js с параметрами тоже. как это можно сделать? Ниже я описал как бы я хотел сделать, ооочень примитивно написал. Если не сложно, то основываясь на этом примере можете объяснить как это можно реализовать? Легкий пример кода:

js:

```
    $('#button_1').on('click', function(){
        $.ajax({
            url:'Index.php',
            success:function(data){
                тут вызов функции code php с некоторыми параметрами которые она принимает
            }
        });
    })
function script(a, b, c){
    a = b + c;
}
```

php:

```
function code($a, $b, $c){
    $a += $b;
    вызов функции script с некоторыми параметрами
}
```

Кнопка:

```
<form method="post" action="">
                    <ul class="buttons_menu">
                        <li>Локации</li>
                        <li ><span ><button id="location_button_1" name="location_button_1">Главные ворота</button></span><em>3 сек.</em></li>
                        <li><span><button id="location_button_2" name="location_button_2" >Торговый квартал</button></span><em>2 сек</em></li>
                        <li><span><button id="location_button_3" name="location_button_3" >Замок</button></span><em>5 сек</em></li>
                        <li><span><button id="location_button_4" name="location_button_4" >Гильдия</button></span><em>4 сек</em></li>
                    </ul>
                        </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Вызвать php код из js невозможно. Вам нужно написать обработчик на сервере, делать ajax запрос и при успешном выполнении возвращать нужные данные в js функцию.

Comment: Я знаю, что фактически это невозможно. Поэтому я и задал вопрос и спросил, что нужно сделать. Расскажете пожалуйста о этом способе, который вы описали?

Answer (score 1):

Кирилл, приветствую!

Вам необходимо в ajax запросе передать необходимые параметры PHP скрипту, в нём произвести необходимые манипуляции и вернуть данные, например в json массиве.

```
 $.ajax({
        url:'Index.php',
        method: 'get',             /* Метод передачи (post или get) */
        dataType: 'json',          /* Тип данных в ответе (xml, json, script, html). */
        data: {a: 10, b: 20}, 
        success:function(data){
            Здесь вы работаете уже с полученными из скрипта данными
            alert(data.a);
            alert(data.b);
            alert(data.ab);
        }
    });
```

success:function(data) -> переменная data - это то, что вы вернете в php скрипте в json

Index.php выглядит примерно так:

```
if($_GET['a'] and $_GET['b']){
    $data['ab'] = $_GET['a'] + $_GET['b'];
    $data['a'] = $_GET['a'];
    $data['b'] = $_GET['b'];
}

$json = json_encode($data);
echo $json;
exit();
```

Comment: А нужно создавать файл json?

Comment: Нет, вам нужно обычный PHP массив перекодировать в json функцией json_encode(). Эта функция по сути создаст строку из массива, которую вы выводите на экран с помощью echo.

Comment: Запустите php скрипт, который я Вам указал в примере, и увидите результат работы. Не забудьте указать GET параметры index.php?a=15&b=30

Comment: $('#location_button_1').on('click', function(){
    $.ajax({
        url:'Game.php',
        method: 'post',             /* Метод передачи (post или get) */
        dataType: 'json',          /* Тип данных в ответе (xml, json, script, html). */
        data: {a: 10, b: 20}, 
        success:function(data){
            
            alert("asd");
        }
    });
})

Comment: Не обрабатывает событие

Comment: Скиньте пожалуйста код кнопки, на которую "вешаете" событие. Её id точно раве "location_button_1"?

Comment: Я изменил код в вопросе, добавил форму с кнопкой в конец

Comment: Код не работает когда пишешь dataType